# Member variable resetting back to 0

Tags: c++, class

When running through the test the count variable from the class stack1 gets reset back to 0 when using its pop function. Strangely however, during the push loop, the count increases as intended but when pop occurs, the count gets reset back to 0 and subtracts into the negatives from there. Is there something I'm forgetting?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TheStack
{
    public:
        TheStack();
        void push(int);
        int pop();
        bool isEmpty();
    private:
        const int MaxSize = 10;
        int arr[10];
        int count;
};

TheStack::TheStack()
{
    count = 0;
}

void TheStack::push(int userInput)
{
    if (count >= MaxSize)
    {
        cout << "Stack is full." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        arr[count] = userInput;
        count+=1;
    }
}

int TheStack::pop()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        cout << "Stack is empty." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        int temp = arr[count];
        arr[count] = NULL;
        count-=1;
        return temp;
    }
}

bool TheStack::isEmpty()
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}



int main()
{
    TheStack stack1;
    if (stack1.isEmpty())
    {
        cout << "isEmpty() works" << endl;
    }

    stack1.pop();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        stack1.push(i);
    }

    stack1.push(0);

    stack1.pop();
    stack1.pop();
    stack1.pop();
    stack1.pop();

    system("pause");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `push` you first save the data into the array and then increment `count`. This means that in order to properly do `pop` you need to work in reverse: *first* decrement `count` and *only then* read data from the array.

But in the code you are doing it backwards. When the stack is full, `count` is at max value (`10` in your case), and your `arr[count] = NULL;` writes beyond the array boundary. This causes undefined behavior and, in particular, destroys your `count` value. (This is why it suddenly becomes `0`.)

Also:

1. `arr[count] = NULL;` makes no sense. `NULL` is supposed to be used in pointer contexts, not in integer contexts. This is not even guaranteed to compile.

   What is the point of that anyway? Initially your array contains garbage above the current top of the stack. Why do you suddenly care to clean it up after doing `pop`?
2. Not all control paths of `pop()` return value. This is undefined behavior in itself.
3. `const int MaxSize = 10;` in the class definition is a C++11 feature. Since you are already using C++11, you can do the same for `count`. Just do `int count = 0;` right inside the class definition and you will not have to write the constructor explicitly.

   Although in your implementation `MaxSize` would make more sense as a `static const` class member. In that case you'll also be able to declare your array as `int arr[MaxSize];`.

Comment: For the NULL I just wanted to make it clear that the array "popped" off the member for the assignment's purpose. Not sure if there's a better way to do it than just reassigning it to 0?
Also for pop(), do I need to change it? If I return something then the cout in main would spit that value out.

Comment: @Michael Li: If you want to set it to `0`, set it to `0`. Not to `NULL`. `NULL` is completely out of place in this context. But again, nothing bad will happen if you just leave the array element unchanged after `pop`.

Answer (score 0):

You must first decrease `count` and then access `arr[count]` in `int TheStack::pop()`. Now you get access above the last pushed element, event out of bound of array if the stack is full.